# Can't understand why I can't loop %[^/n]

Tags: c, loops, scanf

I can't seem to find where the problem is in here.

During the first loop, I can enter the name of the creditor but I can't do that during the second loop.

```
int main(){
    float cb,ir,si,sum=0,totaldebt;
    int time,i;
    char name[25];
    printf("------------Welcome to Debt Management System-------------");

    for (i=1;i>=1;i++){
        printf("\n%d)Name of the creditor: ",i);
        scanf("%[^\n]",&name);
        printf("Enter your current balance: ");
        scanf("%f",&cb);
        printf("Enter its interest rate: ");
        scanf("%f",&ir);
        printf("Enter time for the loan: ");
        scanf("%d",&time);
        si=cb*ir*time/100;//simple interest
        totaldebt=si+cb; //simple interest + current balance

        if (name=='none'){
            break;
        }
    sum+=totaldebt;
}
```

It skip the `scanf` part and I somewhat guess that the reading part seems stuck by it's previous reading.

Comment: Some [MCVE] is needed: what is `name`, for instance?

Comment: What do you expect `scanf("%[^\n]*c",&name);` to match? Scanf patterns are not regular expressions; both `*` and `c` will match only themselves (and that is guaranteed to fail).

Comment: People... you are answering in the comment section!

Comment: forgot to add the initialization sorry..

Answer (score 3):

To get the effect you seem to be after, `%[^\n]*c` should be `%[^\n]%*c`. You need a specifier for the first pattern and then a specifier for a single character. The way you have it written now has you asking `scanf` to match everything up to a newline, and then read the sequence `*c`.

It can't read that sequence, but it matches the first specifier. So you end up with an unconsumed newline that is probably tripping your other input.

There's also the potential problem of your `for (i=1;i>=1;i++)`, that condition is fishy, and likely to go on for a while.

Now, while this is all probably a fun exercise, I suggest you ditch `scanf` and switch to `fgets` to read lines of input. It's less cryptic, and it forces you to pass a buffer size, which makes using it somewhat easier and safer compared to `scanf`.

Comment: "should be %[^\n]%*c" --> `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",name)`; is akin to `gets(name);` and neither should be used.

Comment: @chux - Not quite like `gets`, because `scanf("%25[^\n]%*c",name)`, but there is *no* way to make `gets` safe. And besides, I conclude with `fgets` being a superior alternative anywhere.

Comment: `scanf("%25[^\n]%*c",name)` is not safe either and it can overfill `char name[25];` and also has trouble with the corner case with input like `"\n"`, leaving `name[]` unassigned.  Yes `fgets()` is better, yet then obliges`fgets()` with other input to do something to consume the `\n` after `scanf("%d",&time);` - which is what is suggested here - yet IMO, not clearly for all lines.

Comment: @chux - You know you can post another answer, right?

Answer (score 3):

To complete the first answer, I noticed this problem:

```
if (name=='none')
{
    break;
}
```

This form is not correct in C, you should:

- use [`strcmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) 
  function,
- use `"` instead of `'` to define a string:

```
/* if two strings are the same --but not necessary at the same adress-- strcmp return 0*/
if (0 == strcmp(name, "none"))
{        
    break;
}
```

Comment: you could also do `if(!strcmp(name, "none"))` since `0` is treated the same as `false` in condition statements

Comment: @Tau: it’s better to use the explicit relational operators with `strcmp()` on the left as the operator then reflects the test the comparison is making. That is, `strcmp(a, b) == 0` tests for equality, `strcmp(a, b) >= 0` tests whether `a` is greater than (sorts after) `b`, etc.  the comparison is always with0, of course.

Comment: The lack of `strcmp()` in `if (name == 'none')` is only half of the problem. The other half is that `'none'` is not a C string constant but a character constant (and rather a strange one): [**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/EnI9Rm). (And this said, I ignore that `char*` is compared with `char` - I wonder that the compiler accepted it at all. To my surprise, it did.)

Answer (score 0):

While taking a string input you are not required to use the reference operator '&'. That's why in your first scanf statement use name instead of &name. Also modify the input statement with %*c if you want to take newline character in the input as shown below. Other errors have been stated in the above answers.
scanf("%[^\n]",name); OR
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",name);